# Prevent some items to be filtered in Google Combochart view

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a category filtering combochart, which is perfectly working with the following code:

```
var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
        columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
        
        
        var initState= {selectedValues: []};
        // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
        for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
            columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
            
            // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
            initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
        }

          var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'ColumnChart',
            containerId: 'myPieChart2',
            dataTable: data,
            options: {
                
                height: 300,
                hAxis: {
                  title: 'Time'
                },
                vAxis: {
                  title: 'Flight Hours (min)'
                },
                title: 'Annual Flight Times by Pilot',
                bar: {groupWidth: '90%'},
                seriesType: 'bars',
                series: {
                    0: {type: 'line',
                        lineDashStyle: [4, 4]},
                    1: {type: 'line',
                        lineDashStyle: [14, 2, 2, 7]},
                }
                
                //theme: 'material'
                
            }
        });

      var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
            containerId: 'colFilter_div2',
            dataTable: columnsTable,
            options: {
                filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
                ui: {
                    label: 'Pilots',
                    allowTyping: false,
                    allowMultiple: true,
                    allowNone: false,
                    //selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
                }
            },
            state: initState
        });

              function setChartView () {
            var state = columnFilter.getState();
            var row;
            var view = {
                columns: [0]
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
                row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
                view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
            }
            // sort the indices into their original order
            view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
                return (a - b);
            });
            chart.setView(view);
            chart.draw();
        }
        google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);
        
        setChartView();
        columnFilter.draw();

    });
```

In my data, first two columns (Series 0 and Series 1) belongs to Total and Average of the relevant months. So, I would like to make them constant, which means that they can not be closed (See the image).

Alternatively, if there is a method to exclude them from dropdown & filtering options, but still show at the chart, this can be accepted. In the end, I would like to prevent user to close these items.

How can I do that? I spent two hours for it but still I am stucked.

Thanks for your help in advance.

[image: Total and Average columns can be closed by clicking the X buttons]